# Optimization suggestions for a Python function to improve performance

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, odoo, odoo-16

I'm trying to improve a Python function _read_format in odoo framework, which is responsible for returning a list of dictionaries mapping field names to their values. Each dictionary represents a record. The function works as expected, but I'm interested in optimizing it for better performance.This function is fetching the data from the database then converting it into python objects.

Here is the git link [text](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/16.0/odoo/models.py#L3146)

Here's the code for the _read_format function:

```
def _read_format(self, fnames, load='_classic_read'):
    """Returns a list of dictionaries mapping field names to their values,
    with one dictionary per record that exists.

    The output format is similar to the one expected from the `read` method.

    The current method is different from `read` because it retrieves its
    values from the cache without doing a query when it is avoidable.
    """
    data = [(record, {'id': record._ids[0]}) for record in self]
    use_name_get = (load == '_classic_read')

    for name in fnames:
        convert = self._fields[name].convert_to_read
        for record, vals in data:
            # missing records have their vals empty
            if not vals:
                continue
            try:
                vals[name] = convert(record[name], record, use_name_get)
            except MissingError:
                vals.clear()

    # return values
    return [vals for record, vals in data if vals]
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions or improvements to make this function run more efficiently. If you have any insights, recommendations, or alternative approaches, please share them. Thanks in advance!

```
use_name_get = (load == '_classic_read')
vals = [{'id': record._ids[0], **{name: self._fields[name].convert_to_read(record[name],
                                                                 record,
                                                                 use_name_get)
                       for name in fnames}} for record in self]
```

The time remains the same even with this comprehension.